# Was given a GnuPG v1.4.5 public key file. Is there a simple dummy proof tool that can encrypt files on OSX?

Tags: public-key-encryption, pgp, gnupg, openpgp

I almost had to deal with PGP encryption before and all I remember was that it confused the heck out of me. Today, a client threw a curveball at us telling us we have to encrypt our CSV files before passing them over through FTP. They sent us a public key. Unfortunately, we will have fairly non-tech savvy people handling the CSV files and encrypting them and last time I remember there was quite a bit of command lining I had to do and initial setup of stuff in keychain or something. Is there a simple tool that I can walk the CSV managers through to set up their system and use a nice GUI tool to encrypt the file? Or do we have to do a crazy manual command line setup? I work remotely from the CSV managers so it isn't easy for me to figure it out on my system first and then try to mirror what I did here on their system. The managers are all running at least OSX Snow Leopard and I am on Lion

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[GPGMail](https://www.gpgtools.org/gpgmail/index.html) is pretty easy to use, although not easy to setup. Unfortunately it doesn't work in Mountain Lion yet.

Do you have to use public/private key encryption? If they're okay with shared key encryption, creating AES-encrypted disk images is fairly easy under OS X: http://blog.makezine.com/2007/03/18/how-to-create-an-encrypted-dis/

Comment: I think avoiding as much manual setup as possible would be best. Think of these guys as non-tech savvy project managers :).

Would something like this work? https://www.igolder.com/pgp/encryption/ PGP is still pretty new to me so I'm wondering if there is some kind of private key (owned my iGolder) attached to this tool and the receiving user would need to decrypt it using iGolder's tools as well, which wouldn't work.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like this is not the case. Could this be the answer I'm looking for?

Comment: It looks like that's limited to plain text, so it might not be easy to incorporate it in a workflow for sending spreadsheet attachments. As far as initial setup, I was thinking you could do that part, and then teach them how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

GPG Tools is also very straight foreward - here is a super article about it: https://www.deepdotweb.com/2015/02/20/pgp-tutorial-os-x/ or directly the [GPG Tools Help Page](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/gpgservices-faq/how-to-encrypt-and-sign-text-or-files-with-gpgservices)

Any File can then be encrypted just using the mac os x right click menu.

It is quite easy, but you will not be able to avoid a bit of setup.